# Why am I getting this Python datetime error?

Tags: python

In the following code, I'm trying to download earnings data using Python and the Yahoo Earnings Calendar library.  However, I'm having problems with dates.  I'm trying to create a date range with the start date being the date the code is executed and the end date the following day.  Here is my code:

```
# Set date range
DAYS_AHEAD = 1

# This works
# start_date = dt.date(2021, 4, 14)

# This doesn't work
start_date = dt.datetime.today()
# This doesn't work either
start_date = dt.datetime.now()

# This works for the end date when I use the first start_date declared above
end_date = dt.date(2021, 4, 14) + timedelta(days=DAYS_AHEAD)

# Download earnings calendar
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
earnings_list = yec.earnings_between(start_date, end_date)
```

The last statement which fetches the list of earnings is raising the following error:

```
    TypeError: When either from_date or to_date is not a datetime.date object.
    127         """
--> 128         if from_date > to_date:
    129             raise ValueError(
    130                 'From-date should not be after to-date')

TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

If I type the code above that sets the start and end dates in the Python REPL I see the following:

```
>>> type(start_date)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>>type(end_date)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Also if I run commands below in order to tell which variable has which type so I can figure out which one I need to convert to the type of the other variable, they all return "True".

```
>>> isinstance(start_date, datetime.datetime)
>>> isinstance(start_date, datetime.date)
>>> isinstance(end_date, datetime.datetime)
>>> isinstance(end_date, datetime.date)
```

They both seem to be of the same class and type, so why can't I compare them to each other?  How do I convert one of the dates to the same type as the other so that the comparison will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime`s inherit from both `date` and `time` (makes sense, yeah?), so that's why the `isinstance` checks return true.

If you don't need a time component, only play with `date`s:

```
import datetime

DAYS_AHEAD = 1
start_date = datetime.date.today()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=DAYS_AHEAD)

# Download earnings calendar
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
earnings_list = yec.earnings_between(start_date, end_date)
```

If you already have a `datetime.datetime` object, you can extract the date with `.date()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 13, 22, 20, 38, 257608)
>>> today = right_now.date()
datetime.date(2021, 4, 13)
```